# Seach and delete lines before and after a matching a pattern

Tags: awk

The input contains calendar entries framed by { and },
I want to cut out all Mozilla created entries, looking like below and save the result in a new file.

```
        { 
                       "c_content" = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
    PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN 
    VERSION:2.0 
    BEGIN:VTIMEZONE     
    ..
    END:VCALENDAR"; 
                       "c_name" = "0000000-0000-000-0000-00000000000.ics"; 
                   },
```

The content of one calendar entry is always 39 lines in summary.

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="};"}/Mozilla.org\/NONSGM/;END{printf "\n"}' inputfile
```

This filters out all matching entries but I what to have the opposite result (like a grep -v).

```
 Input sample:
```

The second calendar entry containing the line
*"PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN"*
should be filtered out.

```
                {
                    "c_content" = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Inverse inc./SOGo 5.1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
LAST-MODIFIED:20210303T135712Z
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20180518T085937Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180518T090431Z
DTSTAMP:20180518T090432Z
UID:005A3BF6-39A9-4771-8170-FD9E74AA818B
SUMMARY:Firma Byom
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180518T130000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20180518T140000
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Prospekt \U00DCbergabe
SEQUENCE:1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:NONE
TRIGGER;VALUE=DATE-TIME:19760401T005545Z
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";
                    "c_name" = "005A3BF6-39A9-4771-8170-FD9E74AA818B.ics";
                },
                 {
                    "c_content" = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Mozilla.org/NONSGML Mozilla Calendar V1.1//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:W. Europe Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=3;BYMINUTE=0
TZNAME:Mitteleurop\U00E4ische Zeit
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0
TZNAME:Mitteleurop\U00E4ische Sommerzeit
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20220330
DTSTAMP:20220406T184433Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20220329
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:This entry has to be filtered out
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000000015970CF649D801000000000000000
 0100000001EAC086F1BE63E448C32EE561BCB4A1E
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";
                    "c_name" = "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000000015970CF649D8010000000000000000100000001EAC086F1BE63E448C32EE561BCB4A1E.ics";
                },
                {
                    "c_content" = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Inverse inc./SOGo 5.1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Berlin
LAST-MODIFIED:20210303T135712Z
X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Berlin
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
DTSTART:19700329T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
DTSTART:19701025T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20200124T121710Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20200310T145851Z
DTSTAMP:20200310T145853Z
UID:0085F167-6A6E-4D8D-BE15-F1CAEF2C6CD0
SUMMARY:Herr Mayer
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20200127T083000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Berlin:20200127T093000
CLASS:PUBLIC
DESCRIPTION:Besuch 
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";
                    "c_name" = "0085F167-6A6E-4D8D-BE15-F1CAEF2C6CD0.ics";
                },
```

Comment: Can you provide a more complete sample input file, including entries you want to keep as well as those you want removed?

Comment: please provide, sample input with sample desired output.

Comment: When you have a custom format, it is almost always better to see if someone has built a working parser to help you parse it, rather than rely on being able to swing together something on the fly.

Comment: Ihave added a sample of three calendar entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest `awk` scripts:

#### script 1, base on counting lines. Assuming each record is 36 lines long

```
awk '{--skip}/Mozilla.org/{skip=36}skip<1{print}' input.txt
```

care for first record 2 lines head, and last record 34 lines tail.

#### script 2, assuming record margin is        `},` . Assuming each record ends with         `},`

```
awk '!/Mozilla.org/{printf "%s",$0 RT}' RS="[[:space:]]*},"  input.txt
```

care for last record tail. Is it ending with `},`

Thanks a lot! Since the records are sadly not all 36 lines long, I tried script 2. I do not get any output with it. When I omit the "!" I do get the Mozilla.org entries, so it seems that the invese with "!" has no effect.

Comment: Wow, great! With {skip=36} I can remove the line with the pattern and the following 35 lines below it, but the two lines above the line with the pattern remain.

Comment: Extending the number to 38 did the job. Chapeau !

Comment: thanks, please inspect my answer updates.

Comment: Oh no, some of the >2.750 calendar entries seem to have more or less than the expected 38 lines and therefore the structure is broken somewhere. Is it possible to fence the matched entry by { },  ?

Comment: Update `RS="[[:space:]]*},"` maybe this will help. Suggesting to play with `RS` variable. `RS` variable is a RegExp responsible to grab/identify `awk` record termination marker (normally newline).

Comment: Also suggest to try `RS="},\n"`

Comment: Hey, that worked now. How crazy is that!  :) Thanks for that condensed command - I never thought you could do that with awk. I am impressed!

Comment: Great news, glad to read that. `awk` is the most powerful text processing tool I know. I strongly advise to develop skill with`awk` if you work with text files. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/index.htm

Comment: Right now I bought the PDF version :) Thanks for that tip too!